What is the command call when I click shutdown on Windows and how do I modify it?
I'm currently using Windows 10, I have a shutdown button like everyone have:
I wonder what command does Windows call when I click this button, I know that there is a shutdown.exe file and the shutdown command. You can use the shutdown -s -t 0 to shut your computer down immediately. But I am still not sure if that is the command that Windows use. Also about the shutdown.exe file, I know its location, but whenever I change its name or move it to another location, it said "You need to provide administor...". How can I do it?
Summary:

What command does Windows use when you click the Shut down button?

How do I modify/move/delete/rename the shutdown.exe file?


I search for the shutdown command but I didn't find anything helpful for my questions. I also find something about "Providing administor permission" but I think this might do sth bad to my belove computer, so I didn't do it.

What is your end goal? What are you really trying to achieve?

windows call InitiateShutdownW. but if you use right menu - from explorer (s_InitiatePowerTransitionThreadProc in authui.dll ) and in case left menu - from some RuntimeBroker.exe -Embedding, started (indirect) by ShellExperienceHost.exe and here called InitiateShutdownW from shutdownux.dll this call go to wininit.exe ( s_WsdrInitiateShutdown -> InternalInitiateShutdown ) anf finally to winlogon.exe ( ShutdownWindowsWorkerThread)
